# Unable to Logout out of PHP Facebook app using $facebook->destroySession();

Tags: php, facebook, logout

I have been trying to create a basic Facebook app using PHP based on the example provided in the Facebook API folder.

The steps that I follow are:

1. Open http://sports-admin.tamu.edu/devsite/sarvesh/facebook-php-sdk-master/examples/test_fb.php
2. Click on Login
3. Enter Facebook username and password on the new page
4. I'm redirected back to ./test_fb.php with my information displayed.
5. I click on Logout and I'm redirected back to original page with the Login link
6. But now when I click on Login, it does not ask me for my credentials and directly logs me in.

Please suggest a method where I will be completely logged out of Facebook and upon clicking on Login I will always be asked my username and password.

Here is the html code:

```
<body>
<h1>php-sdk</h1>

<?php if ($user): ?>
<a href='?logoff' >Logout</a> 
<?php else: ?>
  <div>
    Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>PHP Session</h3>
<pre><?php  print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>

<?php if ($user): ?>
  <h3>Your Display Picture</h3>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <h3><?php echo($user_profile["name"]); ?></h3>
<?php else: ?>
  <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
<?php endif ?>
```

And this is the code block for logging out. This code is written in the same test_fb.php file as the html code above

```
if(isset($_GET['logoff'])=='1'){
$facebook->destroySession();
setcookie("fbs_MY-APP-ID", "", time()-3600);
header("Location: test_fb.php");
}
```

I have scoured stackoverflow for three whole days but nothing seems to work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API provides a logoutURL which will log the user out of their current Facebook account.

You can get it like this

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$params = array('next' => 'http://mysite.com/test_fb.php' );
$logoutURL = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
```

However, logging a user out of Facebook is not an ideal behaviour in my opinion. The whole point of Facebook login is to bypass the manual logging in once the user has authorized the app with his/her Facebook account.

Comment: @AshwinMukhjia Thanks but I had tried the getLogoutUrl method earlier but it takes me to my facebook page, hence i resorted to the said method.

Comment: You also need to specify the params for the logout URL to stay on your site itself. See the documentation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies. I tried this but it does not log me out at all. The page has all my information as before.

Comment: Are you using the logoutURL with an anchor?

Comment: Yes '<a href="<?php echo $logoutURL; ?>">Logout</a>'

Comment: I guess the problem lies with sessions because in the earlier case when it took me to my facebook page, I logged out from there and then visited test_fb.php and it still had all my information